# OpenXava - Al actualizar un campo de tipo referencia, el cambio no se refleja en la vista

Tags: openxava, referencias

Desde un @onChange, al actualizar un campo de tipo referencia éste no se ve reflejado en la vista.

Tengo una clase Tercero (un cliente por así decirlo), que se referencia desde PedidoVenta, que tiene 2 campos de tipo Tercero: el cliente y el cliente a facturar, ambos de tipo Tercero. Lo que quiero es que al cambiar el "cliente", automáticamente se copie al "clienteFactura".

onChange y la copia funcionan perfectos, lo que no me funciona es que no actualiza la propiedad en la vista, siempre se queda el campo blanco.

```
@View(name = "Simple", members="alias")
@Entity @Getter @Setter
public class Tercero extends Identifiable
{
    @Column(length=50) @Required
    String alias;
 }

@View(members = "cliente, clienteFactura")
 @Entity @Getter @Setter
public class PedidoVenta extends Identifiable
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @ReferenceView("Simple")
    @OnChange(AlCambiarPedidoVentaCliente.class)
    Tercero cliente;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @ReferenceView("Simple")
    Tercero clienteFactura;
}

 public class AlCambiarPedidoVentaCliente extends OnChangePropertyBaseAction 
{
    @Override
    public void execute() throws Exception 
    {
        if (getNewValue() == null) return;      
        String idTercero = (String) getNewValue();

        getView().setValueNotifying("clienteFactura.id", idTercero); //No actualiza en vista
        getView().setValue("clienteFactura.id", idTercero); //No actualiza en vista

        Object entity = getView().getEntity();
        PedidoVenta pedidoVenta = (PedidoVenta) entity;
        Tercero clienteAFacturar = MiClaseQueSacaTerceroConGetManager.Buscar(idTercero); //No pongo la clase, pero funciona correcto (comprobado)
        pedidoVenta.setClienteFactura(clienteAFacturar); //No actualiza en vista
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo forzar a que refresque la referencia con el nuevo valor en la vista?

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo un refresh() de la vista al final de la acción debería funcionar:

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
    ...
    pedidoVenta.setClienteFactura(clienteAFacturar); 
    getView().getRoot().refresh(); // AÑADE ESTO
}
```

Esto solo funciona si el pedido ya existe en la base de datos, aunque según el código de tu acción eso siempre es así.

Comment: El pedido todavía no existe en la base de datos. Creo que se necesita algún método a nivel de control o propiedad de vista, que fuerce un refresco de la información desde su valor de propiedad (sin releerla desde la BBDD)

Comment: Si el pedido ya existe, puede asignar el código de cliente a la subvista (con getView().getSubview("clienteFactura").setValue("codigo", codigoCliente) y después haces un refresh() de esa subvista con getView().getSubview("clienteFactura").refresh(). Por ejemplo.